# Concatenated routes, can i do this in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Have a list of providers with a three filters (location, category, event type), i need to concatenate filters in routes for make the url more friendly, it would be like ej.: mysite.com/filter/location/cordoba/eventtype/weeding/category/travels
these filters are not required, so i can filter for only location, or location and category, event type and category, etc.. now my question is, ¿could i do that in laravel 5.2?

i before do this like this:

```
    Route::get('/filtro/localidad/{localidad?}', [
        'uses' => 'ProviderController@filterLocation',
        'as' => 'site_filter_location_path'
    ]);

    Route::get('/filtro/tipo_evento/{event_type?}', [
        'uses' => 'ProviderController@filterEventType',
        'as' => 'site_filter_event_type_path'
    ]);

    Route::get('/filtro/rubro/{caption?}', [
        'uses' => 'ProviderController@filterCaption',
        'as' => 'site_filter_caption_path'
    ]);
```

i need something like this (it send me a error where i put only one or two parameters)

```
Route::get('/filtro/location/{localidad?}/event_type/{event_type?}/caption/{caption?}', [
    'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
    'as' => 'site_filter_path'
]);
```

Let's say that I search by location and category, then the url would be like this: mysite.com/location/cordoba/event_type//caption/travel This generates a bad url which gives me error, then how can I do this?

Comment: Apart from this being hackable or not, you might want to take into consideration that while it is theoretically (as per RFC) acceptable to have double slashes in URLs, you never know what certain browsers or link processors like google do with it. I'm with laravel when it thinks that it's a bad url.

Comment: Thanks for answer, now for laravel it is a bad url, so i cant make an url with double slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel will not know how to find your route every time you have a missing parameter, so you cannot really rely on

```
Route::get('/filtro/location/{localidad?}/event_type/{event_type?}/caption/{caption?}', [
    'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
    'as' => 'site_filter_path'
]);
```

You should have something like
   Route::get('/filtro/location/{localidad}/event_type/{event_type}/caption/{caption}', [
        'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
        'as' => 'site_filter_path'
    ]);

So in this case you can call

```
/filtro/location/Santito/event_type/Fiesta/caption/false
```

To be sure there would not have missing parameters.

**What I prefer to do**

Filtering is something hard to put in URLs. Every time you have a new filter, you'll get a new url and that's not good at all, because it gets messy really fast. What people do, usually is to have an endpoint only for the filter, and use url parameters to configure the filter. Laravel pagination is a kind of filter that does not uses route, but url parameter. So I would do

```
Route::get('/filtro', [
    'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
    'as' => 'site_filter'
]);
```

And a controller like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProviderController extends Controller
{
    private function buildFilter($request, $query)
    {
        if ($localidad = $request->get('localidad')) {
            $query->where('localidad', $localidad);
        }

        if ($tipoEvento = $request->get('tipo_evento')) {
            $query->where('tipo_evento', $tipoEvento);
        }

        ...

        return $query;
    }

    public function filter(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Localidad::newQuery();

        $query = $this->buildFilter($request, $query);

        $query->where('filter something else');

        return view('home', ['data' => $query->get()]);
    }
}
```

Then you only have to make a form using `method="GET"` to filter

```
<form action="/filtro" method="GET">
    ...
</form>
```

And you app should receive requests like

```
/filtro?localidad=Santa Maria&tipo_evento=Fiesta
```

And if you need to hit your own routes, by doing internal filter, you can do things like:

```
Route::get('/filter', function () {
    $items = [
        'localidad' => 'Buenos Aires',
        'tipo_evento' => 'Santa Maria',
        'rubro' => 'Todos',
    ];

    $items = collect($items)->map(function($item, $key) {
        return "$key=$item";
    });

   $filter = implode('&', $items->toArray());

   return redirect()->to('/filter?'$filter);
});
```

In the example `$filter` is `localidad=Buenos Aires&tipo_evento=Santa Maria&rubro=Todos`, so it would call

```
/filter?localidad=Buenos Aires&tipo_evento=Santa Maria&rubro=Todos
```

Comment: You've got a typo there with Localidad::newQyery();

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot, but in my view (the frontend made it so) I have a list with links, so I can not use form. Imginate the ebay filter something like this.

Comment: You don't need to use form, it was only an example.

Comment: I know, but there is my problem, I need to configure the laravel routes to concatenate these parameters without making me throw an error. i think something like this:
`Route::get('/filtro/{event_type?}-en-{location?}/{caption?}', [
        'uses' => 'ProviderController@filter',
        'as' => 'site_filter_path'
    ]);`

but here i need to put a condition in rute, when dont come event_type, caption or location

Comment: Did some edits to clarify your problem and my answer.